# How do I get the mac-address table of a Juniper router using PyEZ? It throws an error when running

Tags: python, juniper, junos-automation, pyez

I have created a simple python script to get the vpls mac table from a rouer using an RPC command. Hower it throws an error when running. Does anybody know what I am doing wrong?

root@ubuntu:~# cat vpls3.py

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
from jnpr.junos import Device
from lxml import etree
import jxmlease

username='lab'
password='lab'

dev = Device(host='10.85.164.172', user=username, password=password, normalize=True)

dev.open()
#invoke the RPC command
sw = dev.rpc.get-vpls-mac-table()
print(etree.tostring(sw, encoding='unicode'))
```

root@ubuntu:~#

Below is the error:

```
root@ubuntu:~# python vpls3.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "vpls3.py", line 13, in <module>
    sw = dev.rpc.get-vpls-mac-table()
NameError: name 'vpls' is not defined
root@ubuntu:~#
```

I have also tried below script:

root@ubuntu:~# cat test1.py

```
from jnpr.junos import Device
from lxml import etree

# Set device information with IP-address, login user and passwort
dev = Device( user='lab', host='10.85.164.172', password='lab')

# Connect to the device
dev.open()

# Get MACs
macs = dev.rpc.get-vpls-mac-table(normalize=True)

# Print response of device
print (etree.tostring(macs))

# Close the connection
dev.close()
```

Same error:

root@ubuntu:~# python test1.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test1.py", line 11, in 
    macs = dev.rpc.get-vpls-mac-table(normalize=True)
NameError: name 'vpls' is not defined
root@ubuntu:~#

Comment: Python does not allow hyphens/"-" for function names. Where did you find the docs/reference for that `get-vpls-mac-table` function?

Answer (score 1):

JunOS RPCs translate to Pyez using underscore:

change it to:

sw = dev.rpc.get_vpls_mac_table()

Answer (score 0):

Thanks! its working now with sw = dev.rpc.get_vpls_mac_table() .

Comment: Just an FYI: You can post this as a comment on the answer that helped you, or even better, [vote up or accept the answer that helped you](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).